# How to get the total revenue of e-commerce tag from 2 datalayer variable?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I am trying to set conversion value in google ad console by using google tag manager and e-commerce tags(purchase.actionField.revenue).

If I push one dataLayer tag in the conversion page, it works well.
But if I push two dataLayer tag in the conversion page, only last dataLayer was reflected to the google ad console.

I want to know how to get (or calculate) total revenue from dataLayer variables and to set it to the conversion value in google ad console.

I already setup google tag manager and e-commerce tag for google analytics. Also I am delivering google ad(gsn) and got conversion value which include only one dataLayer variable per conversion.

Conversion tracking tag for the google ad is fired when DOMReady (It's test purpose). Conversion value is {{conversion_value}} which is defined as a custom javascript.

Push dataLayer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer.push({"ecommerce":{"purchase":{"actionField":{"id":"1234567890","affiliation":"Online Store","revenue":45000,"tax":0,"shipping":0},"products":[{"name":"product_1","id":3594,"price":25000,"brand":"brand_1","quantity":1},{"name":"product_2","id":4525,"price":20000,"brand":"brand_1","quantity":1}]}}});
    dataLayer.push({"ecommerce":{"purchase":{"actionField":{"id":"2345678901","affiliation":"Online Store","revenue":20000,"tax":0,"shipping":0},"products":[{"name":"product_3","id":3083,"price":10000,"brand":"brand_2","quantity":2}]}}});
</script>
```

conversion_value(custom javascript)

```
function(){
  var result_str = google_tag_manager['GTM-XXXXXXXX'].dataLayer.get('ecommerce')['purchase']['actionField']['revenue'];
  var result = parseInt(result_str, 10);
  return result_str;
}
```

I want to set conversion value to the campaign tab in google ad console as total revenue.

Above code, I got 20000 as conversion value. But I want to get 65000 as conversion value. Because 65000 is the revenue of the one conversion.